# Is linear independence preserved through column transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, independence

Let's say you have a $m\times n$ matrix $A$, and the $n$ column vectors are linearly independent. And let's say you have a transformation $T$.

You perform the transformation on each column of $A$, and you get the matrix $B$:
$$T(A) = B$$

My question is, will all the columns of $B$ be linearly independent? Can we prove this for any $T$ and $A$?

Comment: Well, unless you make some assumption on $T$, no: what if $T$ is the mapping from column vectors to the $0$ vector?

Comment: @ClementC. good point..are there criteria for $T$ under which this can be proved?

Comment: If $T$ is an injective linear map, for instance.

Comment: @ClementC. hmm how would we go about proving that?

Comment: Basically, by showing that if $x,y$ are linearly independent and $f$ is injective and linear, then $f(x),f(y)$ are linearly independent (this generalizes to more than two vectors easily, directly or by induction.) To see why, take scalars $\lambda,mu$ such that $\lambda f(x)+\mu f(y) =0$; the goal is to show that $\mu=\lambda=0$. But $0 = \lambda f(x)+\mu f(y) = f(\lambda x+\mu y)$ since $f$ is linear, and thus $\lambda x+\mu y=0$ since $f$ is injective. Thus $\mu=\lambda=0$ since $x,y$ are linearly independent by assumption.

Answer (score 0):

We are given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=n$. Your $T$ is a linear transformation $\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^k$ for some $k$. Every such transformation is of the form $T(\vec x)=C\vec x$ for some $k\times m$ matrix $C$. Thus your question is whether the columns of $B=CA$ are linearly independent. Equivalently, your question is whether or not $\rank B=n$.

Of course, the answer is no in general. If $\rank C<n$, then $\rank CA<n$.

If, however, $C$ is invertible, then $\rank CA=n$.